# Cannot load ntdll.dll

Tags: c++, c++11, static, global, sfml

I have researched this question for a while now and I think I have narrowed my problem down.

This is the error output

```
Critical error detected c0000374
Duke's Army.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

Exception thrown at 0x77E49841 (ntdll.dll) in Duke's Army.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77E7C8D0).
Unhandled exception at 0x77E49841 (ntdll.dll) in Duke's Army.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77E7C8D0).

The program '[14436] Duke's Army.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Call stack is as follows

```
ucrtbased.dll!0f8aa672()    Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ucrtbased.dll] 
[External Code] 
>   Duke's Army.exe!Tile::Tile() Line 19    C++
[External Code] 
Duke's Army.exe!Map::Map(int w, int h) Line 70  C++
Duke's Army.exe!MapGenerator::init(int w, int h) Line 37    C++
Duke's Army.exe!MapGenerator::MapGenerator(int w, int h) Line 13    C++
Duke's Army.exe!PlayGameState::PlayGameState(Game * g) Line 13  C++
Duke's Army.exe!main() Line 11  C++
[External Code]
```

Other answers suggest removing a static member that wasn't declared properly or something akin to that. However, in the (supposed) affected class, there is a static vector that I cannot find a way to remove. Any suggestions?

[This is the class I think the errors occurs from]
(Line 19 in the call stack is the beginning of the definition of the default constructor)

Tile.h

```
class Tile
{
public:
    static std::vector<Tile> tiles;

    // Constructors and methods...

    // Method used in constructors to add to static tiles       
    void Tile::init(const std::string& n, const sf::Color& c) {
        this->name = n;
        this->color = c;
        tiles.push_back(*this);
    }

    Tile(std::string n, sf::Color c) {
        init(n, c);
    };

    Tile() {
        init("bounds", sf::Color::Black);
    }

    const static Tile wall;
    const static Tile floor;
    const static Tile bounds;
    const static float TILE_SIZE;
};
```

Static members are declared in Tile.cpp

```
std::vector<Tile> Tile::tiles = std::vector<Tile>(3);
const Tile Tile::wall("wall", sf::Color::White);
const Tile Tile::floor("floor", sf::Color::Green);
const Tile Tile::bounds;
const float Tile::TILE_SIZE = 16.f;
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is going to be in any declaration code. Check your constructors and methods.

Comment: `const Tile Tile::xxxx` should be `const Tile::xxxx`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Um. I don't think so. Those members (three of them) are `Tile` objects, static to the class `Tile` (which is allowed).

Comment: Does this happen in the debugger? What is the callstack?

Comment: This happens in the debugger. I'll post the call stack with the answer.

Comment: That `tiles.push_back(*this)` seems awefully  suspicious, and a recipe for an infinite loop of pushes if `init` is called from the constructor of Tile.

Comment: Please show Tile::Tile() and annotate which is line 19 in your source.

Comment: Edited OP to show both. Line 19 is beginning of definition of the default constructor for Tile

Comment: OK Now I see it. Thanks. Now think about this. It's impossible to construct a `Tile` without invoking `init()`, which itself constructs a tile when pushing a *copy* of the current tile into your static vector. That copy construction, invokes `init`, which creates a copy...  Do you see the problem?

Comment: I honestly never realized that a default constructor was used when using *this. I'm assuming that's what you mean.

Comment: yeah, I see them. read my prior comment.

Comment: I'm thinking that `push_back` should invoke the copy constructor--which is either not defined or not shown by the way. Watch out for [the Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). Anyway, you're in for a bit of fun because what went into `tiles` (which is incompletely defined: `std::vector` of what?) will not be the object you are creating, but a copy of it. Here's where the Rule of Three may kick in and shoot you in the head if `Tile` is not copyable without a custom copy constructor.

Comment: I suppose a separate registrar would be advisable? Or maybe passing a tile vector where Tile::tiles is used? I see your point either way. Thank you for the help

Comment: @user4581301 so essentially overload the copy constructor is what you're saying?

Comment: The copy constructor problem may kick in later depending on the unknown members of `Tile`. If everything automatically copies, you have no problem here. If, say, you have a pointer... watch out.

Answer (score 3):

Your code default-initializes `Tile::tiles` like this:

```
std::vector<Tiles> Tile::tiles = std::vector<Tile>(3);
```

That construction of `vector` doesn't just set capacity, it creates a vector containing 3 elements, default constructored, which will result in 3 calls to `init`, and in `init` you

```
tiles.push_back(*this);
```

`push_back` attempts to grow the vector by one and then copy-construct the newly added element. The key part here is *grow the vector*.

Again: remember, this is happening during the construction of the vector.

You will either create a new element beyond the target size of the vector or over-write the element currently being populated.

The GNU implementation of std::vector doesn't set the vector size until the constructor has been completed. As a result, you get overwrites:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct S {
    std::string s_;
    static std::vector<S> tiles;

    S() { std::cout << "S()\n"; init("default"); }
    S(const std::string& s) {
        std::cout << "S(" << (void*) this << " with " << s << ")\n";
        init(s);
    }
    S(const S& rhs) {
        std::cout << (void*) this << " copying " << (void*)&rhs << " (" << rhs.s_ << ")\n";
        s_ = rhs.s_;
        s_ += " copy";
    }

    void init(const std::string& s) {
        s_ = s;
        std::cout << "init " << (void*)this << " " << s_ << "\n";
        tiles.push_back(*this);  // makes copy
    }
};


std::vector<S> S::tiles = std::vector<S>(3);

int main() {
    for (const auto& el : S::tiles) {
        std::cout << el.s_ << "\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs http://ideone.com/0dr7L2

```
S()
init 0x9e67a10 default
0x9e67a10 copying 0x9e67a10 ()
S()
init 0x9e67a14 default
0x9e67a14 copying 0x9e67a14 ()
S()
init 0x9e67a18 default
0x9e67a18 copying 0x9e67a18 ()
 copy
 copy
 copy
```

So you are introducing UB during startup of your application.

In the above example, the copy constructor default-initializes its target before performing the copy, and since it's copying itself this results in `rhs.s_` being cleared. This is why we get "`copy`" and not "`default copy`".

--- Edit ---

(invalid, as pointed out by @underscore_d)

--- Edit 2 ---

The MSVC vector implementation does this:

```
explicit vector(size_type _Count)
    : _Mybase()
    {   // construct from _Count * value_type()
    if (_Buy(_Count))
        {   // nonzero, fill it
        _TRY_BEGIN
        _Uninitialized_default_fill_n(this->_Myfirst(), _Count,
            this->_Getal());
        this->_Mylast() += _Count;
        _CATCH_ALL
        _Tidy();
        _RERAISE;
        _CATCH_END
        }
    }
```

The key part being:

```
        _Uninitialized_default_fill_n(this->_Myfirst(), _Count,
            this->_Getal());
        this->_Mylast() += _Count;
```

During the fill, your push_back's will increment `_MyLast` by 3 positions, and then the next line of the ctor will increment `_MyLast` by 3 more.

Here's the same code from above running under Visual Studio: http://rextester.com/WNQ21225

Comment: @user4581301 Yes - see also my edit about wall, floor and ceil.

Comment: "order of initialization is undefined" only between different translation units. Those 2 variables are defined in a single TU. In that case, as with any other `static` objects, the order of initialisation is guaranteed to follow the order of definition. Your last section seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: @user4581301 See edit 2, along with a link to an online visual studio version of the test code.

Comment: @underscore_d doh! duly corrected thanks